# how do I get the mov function to work properly

Tags: python, module, adventure

So, I have this input command that's supposed to give the user unprompted input and if it's an invalid command to output 'input' is an invalid command. However, go north, west, etc. is a valid command but the code does not recognize it as so. Pls help :)

btw, player is a module that has a class in it for moving the player's location.

Code:

```
import world, tiles
from player import Player

game = "play"
while game == "play":
    x = input()
    y = " is not a valid command"
    string = x + y
    
    if x == "go north":
        Player.go_north

    if x == "go south":
        Player.go_south
    if x == "go east":
        Player.go_east

    if x == "go west":
        Player.go_west

    if x == "pick up":
        print("pick up what?")

    else:
        print(string)
```

Comment: First of all you need to create an instances of the class to use them, like `a_player = Player()`, secondly you must add `()` following the name of a method in order to invoke it: i.e. `a_player.go_north()`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple of things wrong potentially. First, `Player.go_*` are being referenced as attributes, but I expect they should be functions if they *do* something?  Technically I guess they could be properties, but this feels like the wrong way to use them.

Second, I think your if/else logic is not what you want.  You check for each direction, but even if it suceeds, it drops down to the next `if` statement.  So what happens is at the last check, if it's not "pick up", it will always print the invalid command string.  You either want every conditional to be part of a `if/elif/else` so that once it hits one, it skips the others, or you need to have a `continue` after any successful check, since if you find a match, you just want to continue with the loop.

So something like:

```py
import world, tiles
from player import Player

player = Player()
game = "play"
while game == "play":
    x = input()
    y = " is not a valid command"
    string = x + y
    
    if x == "go north":
        player.go_north()
    elif x == "go south":
        player.go_south()
    elif x == "go east":
        player.go_east()
    elif x == "go west":
        player.go_west()
    elif x == "pick up":
        print("pick up what?")
    else:
        print(string)
```

Comment: so I did that, and it fixed that issue, but then got an argument error saying I missed 'self' added that in but got this error.

`Player.go_west(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Player is a class, and it sounds like go_north(), etc. are instance methods.  You have to instantiate Player.  Will update example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, so I'll guess, maybe there's a collision between the `from player` statement and the use of `player` as a local variable...you can try renaming `player` to something else, see if that helps.